# Why does "Find a file" search for partial text returns 0 results?

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

In our new SharePoint 2013 environment, whenever we are looking at a Document Library, we see the new "Find a File" text field.  Sometimes we can put in partial data (like for the **Project Name** field, which is a Single line of text) using a * as a wildcard and results are returned properly.  Other times, like for our custom **AFE Number** field, we get 0 results.  We still try using the * as a wild card (both before and after the text we see, and using various combinations of quotations).  I can easily see the results in the list, but SharePoint "Find a File" Search does not find it.  Any ideas on why this is?

Update: I've been able to produce results if I include the first part of the *word* in the search, and end it with a *, as opposed to typing in a * followed by the last part of the search term.

Comment: As per your edit, this is how SharePoint search works: You can only add the * for wildcard search in the end of a word, not in the beginning or middle

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I didn't see it documented that way anywhere.  Write it up as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Done, see below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharePoint Search does not support what they call "Suffix Matching", e.g search strings like

```
*ocument
```

and

```
doc*ent
```

will not work!

You can only do a wildcard search with the prefix matching (ending with the wildcard), like

```
docum*
```

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx)

> Using words in the free-text KQL query
>
> When you use words in a
>   free-text KQL query, Search in SharePoint 2013 returns results based
>   on exact matches of your words with the terms stored in the full-text
>   index. You can use just a part of a word, from the beginning of the
>   word, by using the wildcard operator (*) to enable prefix matching. In
>   prefix matching, Search in SharePoint 2013 matches results with terms
>   that contain the word followed by zero or more characters. For
>   example, the following KQL queries return content items that contain
>   the terms "federated" and "search":
>
> `federated search`
>
> `federat* search`
>
> `search fed*`
>
> KQL queries don’t support suffix matching.